# Double Clicking Asp button in Designer mode creates function in unwanted aspx.cs fle

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

On double clicking the asp:Button in Design mode, a button click function is generated in .aspx.cs file of some other .aspx file. How do I make it such that on double clicking the button, it opens in the same page's cs file?
Note: I am using Visual Studio 2022 (free)

Example :-
I have 2 web pages:-
web.aspx (web.aspx.cs)
web1.aspx (web1.aspx.cs)
Now if I double click on a button in design mode of web.aspx file, then a button_click function is being created in web1.aspx.cs file, but Onclick event is being added to the button in web.aspx.
How do I make it such that on double clicking, the function is created in web.aspx.cs itself ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the value of code behind attribute at the top?

Comment: I have used asp:button :-

'<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6" style="text-align:end">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Font-Bold="True" /></div>
                        <div class="col-6" style="text-align:start">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="btn btn-reset" runat="server" Text="Reset" Font-Bold="True" /></div>
                        </div>'

Like so.

Comment: After double clicking the button in designer mode, 
OnClick="Button1_Click" is added as an attribute in the button, but the function Button1_Click isn't being created in web.aspx.cs, but in web1.aspx.cs
Actually, no matter which button I click on, all functions are getting created automatically in web1.aspx.cs only. 
I want them to be created in their own respective cs files.

Comment: @Chetan Help pls!

Comment: @SquadKiller236,  based on my test, I could not reproduce your problem. I could create the event in their own respective cs files. I recommend that you could delete all your events in web1.aspx and web.aspx and add the events again.

Comment: @SquadKiller236, have you tried my advice?

Answer (score 1):

Most likly the issue is that new page was NOT created by Visual Studio, but you made a copy of the page.

Check the topmost line in the markup page.

so, say the page is called MyUpLoadTest2.aspx

(the "2" kind of gives away the fact that I made a copy of this page).

Note this part:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="MyUpLoadTest2.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="CSharpWebApp.MyUpLoadTest2" %>
```

Check both codeBehind, and make sure it matches the page name (MyUpLoadTest2).

And also check the Inherits in above - again make sure it matches the code behind.

Also, view the code page, and make sure the class name for the page matches the page name.

eg this:

```
public partial class MyUpLoadTest2 : System.Web.UI.Page
```

So, make sure all 3 match.

if the page directive in the markup does not match the correct name, or is pointing to a different code file, then you see the effect you note - the code will be created in the wrong page.

Another issue/thing to avoid?

Don't name the page the SAME as any class you have - including built in ones, as that can say mess things up.

So, for example, you might try to call a page GridView, but there is a gridview control, and thus you don't want your page to have the same name, since then the code behind page class will wind up with the same name as that existing class (built in ones, or even control names).

So, check your page directive.

In many cases, you are better off to create a new blank page, and then cut + paste in the markup between the "form" tags, and leave the rest of the page alone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Then I thought that I did something I don't know. So I created a new asp.net web project. I didn't meet the same problem again. I don't understand why but it is the truth. I use vs2022(free) like you and I thought vs2022 is problematic but it is not faulty.